# Toggling span tag on and off with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to toggle the contents of a span tag on and off using a jquery function.

I'm using a span tag as I want the contents to be inline with the rest of the data on the line when it gets toggled. On page load the image I want to toggle appears inline and in the correct position, however upon toggling the image re appears on the screen on a line below the rest of the contents of the line its supposed to be on.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**TheCodez:**

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnHide').click(function() {
            $('.iotoggle').toggle(0);
        });
        });
```

HTML(XML/XSL):

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="io=1">
        <span class="iotoggle">
            <img src="../images/io/input.png" width="4" height="17" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Input"/>
        </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="io=2">
        <span class="iotoggle">
            <img src="../images/io/output.png" width="4" height="17" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Output"/>
        </span>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: plzSendTheCodez, seriously, post the code :)

Comment: I think you're going to have to post some code. For example, how are you toggling? $(".toggle_span").toggle(function() {... or what exactly?

Comment: code snippets have arrived guys..

Comment: Offhand i'd try removing the "zero" argument from toggle. Second, is it possible you have more images with the same class on the page, IE one further down that is hidden by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted confuses me a bit. I changed your jQuery a bit so items hide or show based on the click of the button. (Right now, it looks like you are just hiding based on the button click.) So, now the jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnHide').toggle(function() {
        $('.iotoggle').hide();
    }, function() {
        $('.iotoggle').show();
    });
});
```

Everything stays inline now. [You can see an example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rasvM/). Click the button to toggle the "images" (which are just the alt text right now as I don't have access to your actual images). Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback ain't had a chance to try it out just yet but by the looks of it I can see the problem probably stems from the jquery function I was using. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks.